# addEventListener "click" in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying that my script works when I click the button "Say It". But I cant make it work.

I know that I can put an `onclick` on the html but I need to do it with an `addEventListener` inside the script.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>First Thíngs</title>
  <style>
    input {
      font-size: 2em;
      margin: 10px 1px 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Your city: </p>
  <input class="city" type="text">
  <p>Your name: </p>
  <input class="name" type="text">
  <p></p>
  <button id="myButton">Say it !</button>

  <script>
    
    let city = document.querySelector(".city")
    let name = document.querySelector(".name")

    function personData(city, name){
    alert("I'm from " + city.value + " my name is " + name.value )
    }

    document.getElementById("myButton").myButton.addEventListener("click", personData);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myButton").myButton.addEventListener` should be `document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener`

Comment: Still not working. TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.personData

Comment: That is because both `city` and `name` are `undefined` inside `personData`; that happens because the function expects to receive some arguments that you never pass to it, rather than reading the values from your input elements

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", personData);
```

Updated: removed `myButton`.

Comment: This won't work. You're passing the wrong arguments to the function

Comment: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Both `city` and `name` are undefined inside `personData`; that happens because the function expects to receive them as arguments rather than reading the values from your input elements... but you never passed those arguments.

You could change your JavaScript code as follow:

```js
function personData() {
  let city = document.querySelector(".city");
  let name = document.querySelector(".name");

  alert("I'm from " + city.value + " my name is " + name.value)
}

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", personData);
```